# Input "center" not working in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

In fact, I am learning bootstrap, when I want to center an input. It isn't center.

It's weird... It's a problem with my version?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
      <link
         href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
         rel="stylesheet"
         />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go!</button>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need the give your input a size.

If you didn't give the input some kind of width, it will be inline-block, and you take full width.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
      <link
         href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
         rel="stylesheet"
         />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="form-group ">
         <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 30%" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go!</button>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```